# How to run Blazor PWA WebAssembly offline?

Tags: blazor, progressive-web-apps, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I had added the WebAssembly into the desktop, but when I close the visual studio and turn off the wifi, I cant run the WebAssembly in my Desktop. Anyone know how to run WebAssembly in offline?

Comment: What does it mean to put a webassembly on a desktop? It is supposed to be put on a server from which it will be requesting the additional .NET assemblies it needs.

Comment: @GSerg I mean install the WebAssembly through the browser into my Desktop during debugging. So, I dont have to debug everytime. I just run the WebAssembly at my Desktop.

Comment: And what it does when you try to run it?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to test your application when it doesn't have internet connection, you can go to dev tools -> application -> service workers and check the offline box.

the desktop application is similar to the browser page, just that its downloaded.

Comment: This seems like a general comment that doesn't help with the specific problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).